# How to show value of bar at the end of Bar in chart #oracle Apex #Chart

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, anychart

I have a requirement to show the value of bar at the end of bar as shown in the below imgae:
[Chart Image which is showing bar value at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87C5i.png)
[image]

It might be done by Custom XMl, but in which attribute we need to modify?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Select the series, and search for Label, Set Show=Yes, Position=Outside Bar Edge

Answer (score 1):

On Apex 5.1.1, you should

- navigate to Series
- go to Label property
- set "Show = yes"
- set "Position = outside bar edge"

The result looks like the one you described.

---

You didn't specify which Apex version you use. "Custom XML" *sounds like* 4.x. If that's so, sorry - don't have it any more and can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am using Apex 5.0.1, I searched in label property, but couldn't find Position option there. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The default setting is to display the values. Make sure the "values" ​​option is checked in the chart attributes (image below).
[image]
Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:10

If you need to edit the graph xml you can use this documentation: http://6.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/index.html

Go to: Labels and Tootips >>> Data Labels Formatting

Answer (score 0):

(APEX 5.1) Or if you are using stacked bar chart use the following javascript to add total to bar:

Chart -> attributes -> JavaScript Initialization Code:

```
function( options ){

// Set the stackLabel attribute, to display the stack total above the given stack category
options.stackLabel = "on";
return options;
```

}